# Do Parquet compression algorithms apply any compression across two duplicate/near-duplicate columns?

Tags: apache-spark, compression, storage, parquet, snappy

I want to store duplicate columns with the same data under a different column name and want to know how parquet compression algorithms like snappy handle will handle the compression of this data?

Ideally, I would expect no additional data to be stored aside from the new column name (perhaps some form of run-length encoding). However, since Parquet is columnar, I worry that compression is only applied within the columns rather than across columns.

I calculated the storage before and after creating a duplicate column with a different name and found that the total storage used doubled. I would have expected some compression would have occurred.

Answer (score 0):

In Parquet files columns are treated fully separate. Thus having duplicate columns will lead to duplicate space requirements.

If compression were to work on multiple columns at the same time, one couldn't read them independently anymore and thus one of the core features of the file format would be lost.